# Terminal input hidden after interrupting 'read -s'

Tags: linux, sh, stty

Pressing Ctrl-C while waiting for input from operation `read -sp` returns operation back to command line but input given is hidden like it is still running `read -s`.

example

```
#!/bin/sh

sig_handler() {
  echo "SIGINT received"
  exit 1
}

trap "sig_handler" SIGINT
read -sp "ENTER PASSWORD: " password
echo
echo $password
```

which executes normally like:

```
$~ ./example.sh
ENTER PASSWORD:
password
$~ text
-bash: text: command not found
```

but if you press Ctrl-C at ENTER PASSWORD you get

```
$~ ./example.sh
ENTER PASSWORD: SIGINT received
$~ -bash: text: command not found
```

where text or any other following command isn't displayed as input until you refresh with `reset`.

How can you return text to normal input after receiving SIGINT? `read -p "ENTER PASSWORD: " password` is not desired for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `stty sane` to your signal handler so that it restores the terminal to its default state:

```
sig_handler() {
  echo "SIGINT received"
  stty sane
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, I added stty sane and tput rs1 in the sig_handler before without any affect (testing now that works) must have accidentally put it below exit 1 or something. Thanks